# Simp does not use the provided lemma in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving, simplification

I am doing Exercise 2.6 from the [Concrete Semantics](http://www.concrete-semantics.org/concrete-semantics.pdf) book:

> Starting from the type 'a tree defined in the text, define a function contents :: 'a tree ⇒ 'a list that collects all values in a tree in a list, in any order, without removing duplicates. Then define a function sum_tree :: nat tree ⇒ nat that sums up all values in a tree of natural numbers and prove sum_tree t = sum_list (contents t) (where sum_list is predefined).

I have started to prove the theorem not using auto but guiding Isabelle to use the necessary theorems:

```
theory Minimal

imports Main

begin

datatype 'a tree = Tip | Node "'a tree" 'a "'a tree"

fun contents :: "'a tree ⇒ 'a list" where
  "contents Tip = []"
| "contents (Node l a r) = a # (contents l) @ (contents r)"

fun sum_tree :: "nat tree ⇒ nat" where
  "sum_tree Tip = 0"
| "sum_tree (Node l a r) = a + (sum_tree l) + (sum_tree r)"

lemma sum_list_contents: 
  "sum_list (contents t1) + sum_list (contents t2) = sum_list (contents t1 @ contents t2)"
  apply auto
  done

lemma sum_commutes: "sum_tree(t) = sum_list(contents(t))"
  apply (induction t)
   apply (simp only: sum_tree.simps contents.simps sum_list.Nil)
   apply (simp only: sum_list.Cons contents.simps sum_tree.simps  sum_list_contents)
```

Here it arrives to a proof state

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀t1 x2 t2.
   sum_tree t1 = sum_list (contents t1) ⟹
   sum_tree t2 = sum_list (contents t2) ⟹
   x2 + sum_list (contents t1) + sum_list (contents t2) = x2 + sum_list (contents t1 @ contents t2)
```

Where I wonder why `simp` did not use the provided `sum_list_contents` lemma. I know simple `simp` would solve the equation.

What does general `simp` contain that `simp only` would not use in this case?

Comment: It’s probably to do with `+` being left-associative, so you actually have `(x2 + sum_list (contents t1)) + sum_list (contents t2)` and now your lemma LHS doesn’t match any more. I’ll wait for the experts to tell you about the “right” way to fix that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the missing piece is associativity of addition for natural numbers. Adding `add.assoc` to the simpplification rules solves the equation.

Alternatively, the order of operands when defining the tree sum could be changed:

```
fun sum_tree_1 :: "nat tree ⇒ nat" where
  "sum_tree_1 Tip = 0"
| "sum_tree_1 (Node l a r) = a + ((sum_tree_1 l) + (sum_tree_1 r))"
```

Then the associativity is not required:

```
lemma sum_commutes_1: "sum_tree_1(t) = sum_list(contents(t))"
  apply (induction t)
   apply (simp only: sum_tree_1.simps contents.simps sum_list.Nil)
  apply (simp only: sum_list.Cons contents.simps sum_tree_1.simps sum_list_contents)
  done
```